# Execute a SQL Stored Procedure and process the results

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In VB.NET, how do I do the following?

1. Execute a Stored Procedure
2. Read through the DataTable returned

Comment: If you are using 2008, it is possible to return a table.

Comment: @Doug - OP doesn't need 2008 for what he is asking. The results of a stored procedure can be captured by the client application as a dataset *(I don't have a good enough .net background but in Delphi it can)*.

Comment: @Lieven, you're right. OP doesn't *need* 2008 to do what they are asking.

Answer (score 44):

At the top of your .vb file:

```vb
Imports System.data.sqlclient
```

Within your code:

```vb
'Setup SQL Command
Dim CMD as new sqlCommand("StoredProcedureName")
CMD.parameters("@Parameter1", sqlDBType.Int).value = Param_1_value

Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
CMD.Connection = connection
CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 300

'Fill the dataset
Dim DS as DataSet    
adapter.Fill(ds)
connection.Close()   

'Now, read through your data:
For Each DR as DataRow in DS.Tables(0).rows
    Msgbox("The value in Column ""ColumnName1"": " & cstr(DR("ColumnName1")))
next
```

---

Now that the basics are out of the way,

**I highly recommend abstracting the actual SqlCommand Execution out into a function.**

Here is a generic function that I use, in some form, on various projects:

```vb
''' <summary>Executes a SqlCommand on the Main DB Connection. Usage: Dim ds As DataSet = ExecuteCMD(CMD)</summary>'''
''' <param name="CMD">The command type will be determined based upon whether or not the commandText has a space in it. If it has a space, it is a Text command ("select ... from .."),''' 
''' otherwise if there is just one token, it's a stored procedure command</param>''''
Function ExecuteCMD(ByRef CMD As SqlCommand) As DataSet
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("main").ConnectionString
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Try
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        CMD.Connection = connection

        'Assume that it's a stored procedure command type if there is no space in the command text. Example: "sp_Select_Customer" vs. "select * from Customers"
        If CMD.CommandText.Contains(" ") Then
            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Else
            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        End If

        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 300

        'fill the dataset
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        connection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' The connection failed. Display an error message.
        Throw New Exception("Database Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return ds
End Function
```

---

**Once you have that, your SQL Execution + reading code is very simple:**

```vb
'----------------------------------------------------------------------'
Dim CMD As New SqlCommand("GetProductName")
CMD.Parameters.Add("@productID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ProductID
Dim DR As DataRow = ExecuteCMD(CMD).Tables(0).Rows(0)
MsgBox("Product Name: " & cstr(DR(0)))
'----------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

Comment: +1 for the recommndation to abstract into a function.

Answer (score 11):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx)

**To execute a stored procedure returning rows programmatically using a command object**

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim reader As SqlDataReader

cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
' Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.
' Use Read method (true/false) to see if reader has records and advance to next record
' You can use a While loop for multiple records (While reader.Read() ... End While)
If reader.Read() Then
  someVar = reader(0)
  someVar2 = reader(1)
  someVar3 = reader("NamedField")
End If    

sqlConnection1.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way? It works. :)

```
    Dim queryString As String = "Stor_Proc_Name " & data1 & "," & data2
    Try
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConnStrg)
            connection.Open()
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Dim DTResults As New DataTable

            DTResults.Load(reader)
            MsgBox(DTResults.Rows(0)(0).ToString)

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while executing .. " & ex.Message, "")
    Finally
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Stored Procedure Requires 2 Parameters and I needed my function to return a datatable here is 100% working code**

**Please make sure that your procedure return some rows**

```
Public Shared Function Get_BillDetails(AccountNumber As String) As DataTable
    Try
        Connection.Connect()
        debug.print("Look up account number " & AccountNumber)
        Dim DP As New SqlDataAdapter("EXEC SP_GET_ACCOUNT_PAYABLES_GROUP  '" & AccountNumber & "' , '" & 08/28/2013 &"'", connection.Con)
        Dim DST As New DataSet
        DP.Fill(DST)
        Return DST.Tables(0)      
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()

Dim adapter As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Dim dsdetailwk As New DataSet

Try
   adapter = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
   adapter.SelectCommand = cmd
   adapter.Fill(dsdetailwk, "delivery")
   Catch Err As System.Exception
End Try

sqlConnection1.Close()

datagridview1.DataSource = dsdetailwk.Tables(0)
```