# How to Execute a Stored Procedure on VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeletetblOfficeEquipmentProfileRecord
@OE_ID  varchar(11)
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM [EOEMS].[dbo].[tblOfficeEquipmentProfile]
WHERE [OE_ID]=@OE_ID
END
RETURN
GO
```

Above is my sql stored procedure how will I execute in in vb.net 2003

this SP is for delete a records based on an OE_ID  chosen on the textbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991877/vb-net-execute-a-sql-stored-procedure-and-process-the-results

Comment: first, consider upgrading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the following code for executing a stored procedure

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Dim conn as New SqlConnection(YourConnectionString)
Dim cmd as SqlCommand = conn.createcommand
conn.open()
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoreProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@OE", YourValue)
cmd.CommandText = DeletetblOfficeEquipmentProfileRecord
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
conn.close()
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@OE_ID", NVarChar.NVarChar))

error sir, 

Run-time exception thrown : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException - Procedure 'DeletetblOfficeEquipmentProfileRecord' expects parameter '@OE_ID', which was not supplied.

Comment: try with this Dim OE_ID as string = "10" cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@OE_ID", OE_ID))